# Object files are not created in sub directory but in main directory

Tags: makefile

I have the following code in my makefile:

```
#Compiler
CC = g++

IDIR = headers
SRCDIR = sources
ODIR = obj
LIBS = -lncurses
CFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)

DE = Cow.h Sheep.h
DES = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(DE))

_O = Cow.o Sheep.o
OB = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_O))

all: make
    ./make

make: $(OB) $(ODIR)/main.o $(DES)
    $(CC) -W -Wall -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DES)
    $(CC) -W -Wall -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/main.o: $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

But when I run make in the terminal, the object files are being created, but in the project directory (where the makefile is saved) and not in the obj sub directory.

Comment: This makefile looks correct.  Are you sure this is exactly the makefile you're using in your tests?  Do you happen to have a second makefile in the directory that make might be using instead, or maybe when you translated your makefile into the SO question you modified it?  Does the entire thing actually work, but just put the objects in the local directory, or are there errors (and if so, what are they)?

Comment: Yes, it is working, and I copied the exact code from my makefile. The objects were created in the local directory and the only error it gave was
`Cow.o not found in obj/`

Comment: You are using both C and C++ source files? Could you show us the output of Make (the lines it prints, not the files it writes)?

Comment: i checked your makefile its working correctly. objects are being created in obj folder only

Comment: What program printed the error `not found in ...`?  Make won't print that.  There's simply no way that I can see that the makefile above can result in the behavior you describe.  There are many kinds of problems you might have, but the target above depends on files existing in the `ODIR` directory, and it simply won't try to create files in the current directory at all.  Are you sure there's not another makefile being used instead?  As Beta says, you'll have to show us the output from running `make`.  BTW, calling your program `make` is probably not a good idea and will lead to confusion.